# Can't pass multiple locals when rendering JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, locals

I'm trying to render a javascript file (through a remote AJAX call) using the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
                format.js { render "like", :locals => {:media_id => media_id, :like_type => like_type}}
end
```

The file is named "like.js.erb" and I know it will work because when I put just a standard javascript alert in the file, it works perfectly.
The file (like.js.erb) looks like this:

```
<% if like_type == "l" %>
    alert("liking as <%= like_type %> for media_id <%= media_id %>");
    $('like_<%= media_id %>').update("liked");
<% elsif like_type == "u" %>
    alert("unliking as <%= like_type %> for media_id <%= media_id %>");
    $('like_<%= media_id %>').update("unliked");
<% end %>
```

When the file contains the code above, the POST action completes properly but nothing is returned at all. It seems that it doesn't like the multiple locals being passed.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can u explain which code is not executed mentioned in js.erb file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `:locals` option then you need to provide the `:partial` key as a parameter.

```
respond_to do |format|
                format.js { render :partial => "like", :locals => {:media_id => media_id, :like_type => like_type}}
end
```

or:

```
respond_to do |format|
                format.js { render "like", :media_id => media_id, :like_type => like_type}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. How should I reference the variables in the like.js.erb file? Like <%= media_id %> or <%= @media_id %>? I've tried both and for some reason both of those return blank values. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: just <%= media_id %> (unless you are defining @media_id = something). if they return blank values it is because they are nil. is like_type also blank?

Comment: Yes, both are completely blank even though I am sure I am passing data... I will post more info when I get home in hopes you might be able to take a look at it? Thanks so much!